# Conflito de versão bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tenho um arquivo html que usa bootstrap 5, preciso inserir nesse arquivo um componente que usa bootstrap 4. Como evitar o conflito de versões?

Comment: Qual seria esse componente? Provavelmente ele deve existir no bootstrap 5.